# How to pattern match on Constructors in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, modeling, sum-type

I have a state machine where states are implemented using a sum type. Posting a simplified version here:

```
data State = 
    A { value :: Int } 
  | B { value :: Int }
  | C { other :: String }
```

most of my functions are monadic consuming `State`s and doing some actions based on the type. Something like (this code doesn't compile):

```
f :: State -> m ()
f st= case st of  
  s@(A | B) -> withValueAction (value s)
  C -> return ()
```

I know that I could unroll constructors like:

```
f :: State -> m ()
f st= case st of  
  A v -> withValueAction v
  B v -> withValueAction v
  C _ -> return ()
```

But that's a lot of boilerplate and brittle to changes. If I change the parameters to the constructor I need to rewrite all `case .. of` in my codebase.

So how would you pattern match on a subset of constructors and access a shared element?

Comment: Why do you have separate constructors for `A` and `B` in the first place, if they share the same functionality? You may want to refactor your type to have only two constructors, one with an extra field that distinguishes between your former `A` and `B` cases.

Comment: There is [a proposal to add such or patterns to GHC](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/522).

Comment: @leftaroundabout this is just an example. Actual types have more fields but share a bunch. I just wanted to stress that there are fields shared by some but not all constructors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I've picked at the end. My two main requirements were:

1. "Or" pattern matching over constructors
2. Selection of a subset of fields shared by the pattern match

As reported by @Noughtmare 1 is not possible at the moment https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/522.

Since for my problem the source of variability comes mostly from parameters in the constructors and not from the number of states, the solution I picked was to enable [NamedFieldPuns](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/record_puns.html) extension, so the solution is something like:

```
f :: State -> m ()
f st= case st of  
  A {value} -> withValueAction value
  B {value} -> withValueAction value
  C {} -> return ()
```

It has some boilerplate enumerating constructors but at least it has none at the constructor parameters. I'll have a look at the view patterns maybe they are useful when the source of variability comes from the number of constructors and not the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

One way to implement this idiomatically is to use a slightly different `value` function:

```
value :: State -> Maybe Int
value (A v) = Just v
value (B v) = Just v
value _ = Nothing
```

Then you can write your case using a [pattern guard](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-460003.13) like this:

```
f st | Just v <- value st -> withValueAction v
f C{} = return ()
f _ = error "This should never happen"
```

Or you can simplify this a bit further using [view patterns](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/9.4.2/docs/users_guide/exts/view_patterns.html) and even more with [pattern synonyms](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/9.4.2/docs/users_guide/exts/pattern_synonyms.html):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns, PatternSynonyms #-}

pattern V :: Int -> State
pattern V x <- (value -> Just v)

{-# COMPLETE V, C #-}

f (V x) = withValueAction x
f C{} = return ()
```

Answer (score 1):

@Noughtmare's answer demonstrates how you can use view patterns to get the right "pattern matching syntax".  To auto-generate the `value` function that selects a shared field from several constructors, you can use `lens`, though this kind of requires buying into the whole Lens ecosystem.  After:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens
import Control.Lens.TH

data State =
    A { _value :: Int }
  | B { _value :: Int }
  | C { _other :: String }

makeLenses ''State
```

you will have a traversal `value` that can be used to access the partially shared field:

```
f :: (Monad m) => State -> m ()
f st = case st ^? value of
  Just v  -> withValueAction v
  Nothing -> return ()
```